# dlopen causes segfault when running in gdb

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

My project loads a libray (compiled in debug mode) dynamically within the main thread with `dlopen` and then uses `dlsym` without problem. However, when running in debug mode with **gdb 7.7.1+dfsg-5**, it crashes. I see from kernel logs this error:

```
gdb[8814]: segfault at 7fff4e019fa0 ip 0000000000718b95 sp 00007fff4e019f90 error 6 in gdb[400000+574000
```

This causes to me not able to use the debugger. Terrible!

What could I do to fix this?

My project has this complex structure. I know that it has rare structure but I am told to use external library as this.

```
MAIN RUNNABLE (compiled with S1.so)
|
- SHARED_1 (S1.so) (compiled with s1.a, s2.a, s3.a)
  |  - STATIC_1 (s1.a)
       |  - dlopen S2.so and call functions from S2.so
  |  - STATIC_2 (s2.a)
  |  - STATIC_3 (s3.a)
- DYNAMICALLY_LOADING_1 (S2.so) (compiled with s1.a, s2.a, s3.a)
  |  - STATIC_1 (s1.a)
  |  - STATIC_2 (s2.a)
  |  - STATIC_3 (s3.a)
```

Comment: Minimal example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: :( From so huge project I couldn't extract some thing.

Comment: But the problem is with loaded shared library, because other library could be loaded in gdb. How could u reproduce if you don't have that library?

Comment: If it's a public library, tell us the name, version etc.. if not, show us how to produce a library that has the same problems. In any case, we need a minimal example.

Comment: I tried to give the "rare" structure.

Answer (score 2):

Done! It is a bug of `GDB 7.7.1+dfsg-5`.
I have installed `GDB 7.10.1` and now it works!